# OOP in java - creating objects

Tags: java, oop, object

OK guys, up till now (and since I'm a beginner) I was programming Java based on procedural programming and it was nice and all but It's time to use Java like-a-boss.

I'm learning the OOP concept now while writing some code as practice.
What I dont understand is that if I create a few objects this way:

```
    Contact first = new Contact(25, "Yosi", "Male");
    System.out.println("Age of contact " + first.toString() + " is - "
            + first.getAge() + " " + first.getName());

    Contact second = new Contact(22, "lisa", "Femal");
    System.out.println("Age of contact " + second.toString() + " is - "
            + second.getAge() + " " + second.getName());

    Contact third = new Contact(34, "Adam", "Male");
    System.out.println("Age of contact " + third.toString() + " is - "
            + third.getAge() + " " + third.getName());
```

The result will be:

```
Age of contact Contact@173f7175 is - 25 Yosi
Age of contact Contact@4631c43f is - 22 lisa
Age of contact Contact@6d4b2819 is - 34 Adam
```

But if I then try to print the first contact again, it will get the values of the last object created. I mean, for this code:

```
    Contact first = new Contact(25, "Yosi", "Male");
    System.out.println("Age of contact " + first.toString() + " is - "
            + first.getAge() + " " + first.getName());

    Contact second = new Contact(22, "lisa", "Femal");
    System.out.println("Age of contact " + second.toString() + " is - "
            + second.getAge() + " " + second.getName());

    Contact third = new Contact(34, "Adam", "Male");
    System.out.println("Age of contact " + third.toString() + " is - "
            + third.getAge() + " " + third.getName());

    System.out.println("Age of contact " + first.toString() + " is - "
            + first.getAge() + " " + first.getName());
```

the result will be:

```
Age of contact Contact@173f7175 is - 25 Yosi
Age of contact Contact@4631c43f is - 22 lisa
Age of contact Contact@6d4b2819 is - 34 Adam
Age of contact Contact@173f7175 is - 34 Adam
```

I've added up the object string representation so you can see the different objects.
I thought I was creating a new object and each object has it's own instance values?
could you guys explain to me?

This is the contacts class:

```
public class Contact {

    private static int age = 0;
    private static String name = "Unknown";
    private static String gender = "Male";

    public Contact(int a, String n, String g) {
        age = a;
        name = n;
        gender = g;

    }

    public Contact() {
    }

    public static int getAge() {

        return age;
    }

    public static String getName() {

        return name;
    }

    public static String getGender() {

        return gender;
    }

    public static void setAge(int a) {

        age = a;

    }

    public static void setName(String n) {

        name = n;
    }

    public static void setGender(String g) {

        gender = g;
    }

}
```

Please note that if I remove static qualifier I get errors saying "cannot make a static referance to the non static field"

Comment: Please post the code of your Contact class. Most likely, you have static attributes there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove the `static` qualifier from your instance variables and/or methods (age, getAge, name, getName).

Comment: Thank you this is true I'm using static qualifiers but if I remove them I get an error saying I cannot make a static reference to a non static field

Comment: @Yosi199 please post the code of your `Contact` class. It will be easier for others to help you

Comment: Then you are fixing at the wrong end -- change the type of access to non-static instead of making everything downstream static. I bet you are taking Quick Fix as your programming advisor, that's a wrong approach. Quick Fix is here to help people who already know what they want to get it done more quickly.

Comment: BTW Have you made sure that your **methods** `getAge`, `getName` **don't have the static qualifier**?

Comment: Thank you all were right and great help. I removed all static refrences fro the get and set methods and instance variables and it works now.

Answer (score 4):

This can occur if you mistakenly use a static variable:

```
class Stat {
  static String name;

  Stat(String n) {
    name = n;
  }
}
```

In the example class above, all instances will share the same value for `name`.

Use non-static variables for instance members:

```
class Stat {
  String name;

  Stat(String n) {
    name = n;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Well, Yosi.Static qualifiers tie your fields(and methods) to your class not to your object** and each Object of your Class(Contact) share the same value.

Whenever you instantiate it by **New**, this value gets updated. So when you print fourth time the value it has is what you update it in third time. That'y its printing like that.

**As I see you code, if you remove static from everywhere, your code will behave as you desire.**